# Confluent Platform: version-alignment between Confluent Platform and Apache Kafka releases

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

```
OS: ubuntu 18.x
Confluent Schema Registry:  community edition version 5.5.1
Kafka:  AWS MKS (Apache Kafka 2.2.1)
```

I am circling around several issues in relation to expunging topic logs that reference stale schema IDs.  That specific issue was [previously reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58098204/confluent-schema-registry-schema-id-deletion).  Here, I elaborate on related matters.

I decided to delete all logs for my topic -- call it `TOP`.  Following several articles (including [one from Confluent docs](https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.1/kafka/dynamic-config.html#changing-topic-configurations-dynamically)), I tried setting the retention time for my topic to 1s.  Eg:

```
$ ./kafka-topics --bootstrap-server "b-3.amazonaws.com:9092,b-2.amazonaws.com:9092,b-1.amazonaws.com:9092" --alter --config retention.ms=1000 --topic TOP
Option combination "[bootstrap-server],[config]" can't be used with option "[alter]"
...
```

As the output shows here, that command fails and suggests an inappropriate combination of command-line options.  I then tried something similar with `kafka-configs` command:

```
$ ./kafka-configs --bootstrap-server "b-3.amazonaws.com:9092,b-2.amazonaws.com:9092,b-1.amazonaws.com:9092" --entity-type topics --entity-name TOP --alter --add-config retention.ms=1000
Error while executing config command with args '--bootstrap-server b-3.amazonaws.com:9092,b-2.amazonaws.com:9092,b-1.amazonaws.com:9092 --entity-type topics --entity-name call --alter --add-config retention.ms=1000'
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support INCREMENTAL_ALTER_CONFIGS
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:272)
    at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.alterConfig(ConfigCommand.scala:327)
    at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.processCommand(ConfigCommand.scala:298)
    at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand$.main(ConfigCommand.scala:91)
    at kafka.admin.ConfigCommand.main(ConfigCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: The broker does not support INCREMENTAL_ALTER_CONFIGS
```

So, I am suspicious there is a disconnect between the Confluent docs I am referencing and the version of Kafka I am using through AWS MKS.  In this circumstance, what is the recommended practice for setting the topic-specific configuration property?

More generally, can anyone clarify the version alignment between Apache Kafka releases and Confluent Platform?

Comment: This might clarify your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532385/kafka-dependencies-ccs-vs-ce

Comment: That seems right.  Maybe we can lock down the question with a reference to that article.

Comment: You mean to flag your question as duplicate?

Comment: So, I think version-alignment question is answered.  However, after downloading confluent-5.2.2-2.12.tar.gz, other problem persists:  ie, `kafka-topics` command returns same error.  Maybe I should decompose the original question into separate sub-questions, leaving this one for version-alignment -- which would be a dup.